# ESP8266 WiFiEspClient Disconnect 3 with GPS

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, gps

I have recovered an old sketch (2 years ago) in which I used 2 DHT22 sensors and sent the values to an web app to store in database. The sketch works fine with a ES8266 module connected to an arduino uno. In my new project I am trying to do the same action, but sending GPS coordinates obtained with GPS NEO-6m module.

I have write a function that returns a string with the parameters as lat, lng, altitude, and others.

```
void loop(){
  gps_data = get_gps_data();

  // all code for wifi client sending
  ..........
  client.print("GET /reads/store?"+gps_data);
  .......
  .......
}
String get_gps_data(){
  // GPS capture function 
  ...........
}
```

The function takes 5 second in get GPS information but I always get....
TIMEOUT>>>
Disconecting 3
and none call arrives to to web server
but if I change (for example..)

```
gps_data = "gps=1&lat=36.125471&lng=-4.478658.....";
```

the system works fine and send continuously the data, and if I put a delay before and after the gps the system works. If I take a value from DHT22, the code works too, but with the GPS the URL is not sent to the server.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: yes, the gps_data is not what you think it is

Comment: one is on hw Serial other on SoftwareSerial? do you use the WiFiEsp library? at what baud rate?